# Difference between QtGui.QApplication and QtCore.QCoreApplication

Tags: python, qt, pyside, qapplication, qcoreapplication

What is known about QtGui is that it is used for GUI programs to create interfaces, and QtCore is for non-GUI programs and actually works under the interface. But to get the instance of the running application, I found that we can use either QtCore and QtGui to return the current running instance using `QtCore.QCoreApplication` and `QtGui.QApplication`.

So what is the difference between the instance returned using them?
Are they referring to the same thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference because the `instance()` method in `QApplication` is inherited from `QCoreApplication`. You can also demonstrate this as follows:

```
>>> from PyQt4.QtCore import QCoreApplication
>>> from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication
>>> a = QApplication([])
>>> a
<PyQt4.QtGui.QApplication object at 0x02A75620>
>>> QApplication.instance()
<PyQt4.QtGui.QApplication object at 0x02A75620>
>>> QCoreApplication.instance()
<PyQt4.QtGui.QApplication object at 0x02A75620>

>>> b = QCoreApplication([])
>>> b
<PyQt4.QtCore.QCoreApplication object at 0x02A75670>
>>> QCoreApplication.instance()
<PyQt4.QtCore.QCoreApplication object at 0x02A75670>
>>> QApplication.instance()
<PyQt4.QtCore.QCoreApplication object at 0x02A75670>
```

Note that PyQt is correctly typecasting the object regardless of which class you use to access the instance. In C++, you would need to do this typecasting yourself.

Comment: The `instance()` method exists in both classes because QApplication inherits it from QCoreApplication. In either case you're calling the same method, which returns whatever you instantiated your application as. Of course in C++ you may need to typecast the return value...

Comment: @user3419537 You're right. I'd sort of assumed they'd overridden it to return the correct type for the class you were calling it from, but I guess there is no point (assuming you can even do that in C++?)

Comment: Thanks .. simple and explanatory

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `shiboken` module to check what is really happening:

```
>>> import shiboken
>>> from PySide import QtCore, QtGui
>>> app = QtGui.QApplication([])
>>> app
<PySide.QtGui.QApplication object at 0x7fc6031c98c8>
>>> print(shiboken.dump(app))
C++ address....... PySide.QtGui.QApplication/0x11446c0
hasOwnership...... 0
containsCppWrapper 1
validCppObject.... 1
wasCreatedByPython 1

>>> print(shiboken.dump(QtGui.QApplication.instance()))
C++ address....... PySide.QtGui.QApplication/0x11446c0
hasOwnership...... 0
containsCppWrapper 1
validCppObject.... 1
wasCreatedByPython 1

>>> print(shiboken.dump(QtCore.QCoreApplication.instance()))
C++ address....... PySide.QtGui.QApplication/0x11446c0
hasOwnership...... 0
containsCppWrapper 1
validCppObject.... 1
wasCreatedByPython 1

>>> print(shiboken.dump(QtGui.qApp))
C++ address....... PySide.QtGui.QApplication/0x11446c0
hasOwnership...... 0
containsCppWrapper 1
validCppObject.... 1
wasCreatedByPython 1
```

As you can see, the same underlying C++ object is being referenced each time. And if you created a `QCoreApplication`, the same `QCoreApplication` would be referenced each time as well.

The intention here is that there should only ever be *one* application object. But the Qt classes are not really true singletons. As a consequence of this, PySide chooses to raise an error if you try to create another instance:

```
>>> app2 = QtGui.QApplication([])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
RuntimeError: A QApplication instance already exists.
```

In PyQt, though, there is nothing to stop you creating multiple instances, and the same must be true in C++. Presumably it is documented somewhere that this will usually result in undefined behaviour.

Using `sip.dump` with PyQt shows some other important differences:

```
# NB: abbreviated output
>>> import sip
>>> from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
>>> app = QtGui.QApplication([])
>>> sip.dump(app)
<PyQt4.QtGui.QApplication object at 0x7fc801a91678>
    Reference count: 3
    Address of wrapped object: 0x25190e0
    Created by: Python
    To be destroyed by: Python
>>> sip.dump(QtCore.QCoreApplication.instance())
<PyQt4.QtGui.QApplication object at 0x7fc801a91678>
    Reference count: 3
    Address of wrapped object: 0x25190e0
    Created by: Python
    To be destroyed by: Python
>>> sip.dump(QtGui.QApplication.instance())
<PyQt4.QtGui.QApplication object at 0x7fc801a91678>
    Reference count: 3
    Address of wrapped object: 0x25190e0
    Created by: Python
    To be destroyed by: Python
>>> sip.dump(QtGui.qApp)
<PyQt4.QtGui.QApplication object at 0x7fc801a91558>
    Reference count: 3
    Address of wrapped object: 0x25190e0
    Created by: C/C++
    To be destroyed by: C/C++
```

Note that, unlike PySide, the `qApp` instance is created by C++, rather than Python, and the PyQt wrapper is *not the same*. This is an important point to remember if you ever decide to create your own subclass of `QApplication`, because `qApp` will simply ignore it! If you want `qApp` to reference your own subclass, you need to explicitly set it, like this:

```
myapp = MyCustomApplication(sys.argv)
QtGui.qApp = myapp
```

In PySide, this little hack is not needed.